# Persist Variable in Base SAS

Tags: sas

I am using SAS on OS390.

I have an INFILE1, some treatment, then another INFILE2, other treatment.

I want to use variables from INFILE1 to compare with INFILE2.

examples:

```
INFILE1.DATE1 > INFLE2.DATE2 THEN OUTPUT;
```

My issue is that DATE1 is always empty no matter what.
I've tried....

```
%LET DATETEMP = INFILE1.DATE1
```

...but `DATETEMP` is empty as well.

Is there any way in SAS to make a variable carry its value from an INFILE to another...so to speak?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare variables across datasets in one datastep. You have to merge the datasets first and then make the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a datastep merge or an SQL Join

**Merge Example:**

```
DATA want ; 
    MERGE INFILE1 INFILE2; 
    BY ID ;
RUN;
```

**SQL Join Example:** (you can do either inner or left join based on what you want)

```
proc sql;
create table work.want as 
select t1.date1 , t2.date2, t1.id
from INFILE1 as t1 
left join INFILE2  as t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
/*inner join INFILE2  as t2 on t1.id=t2.id;*/
quit;
```